# if and else statements inside a while loop won't work

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to create an `alert` asking about the user email and if it's compatible to the stored variable, Then an alert will appear with Logged! message but the loop doesn't work with my code only `if` and `else` does but only for one time.

```js
//working code
function validation(str) {
  var str = prompt("Please Enter your email");
  var email = "plapla@gmail.com";

  if (str === email) {
    return alert("Welcome back, Logged Successfully!" + " your email is " + str);
  } else {
    return alert("Your Email is incorrect, Please Try again");
  }

}

validation();
```

```js
//Loop Code
function validation(str) {
  var str = prompt("Please Enter your email");
  var email = "plapla@gmail.com";
  while (str !== email) {
    if (str === email) {
      return alert("Welcome back, Logged Successfully!" + " your email is " + str);
    } else {
      return alert("Your Email is incorrect, Please Try again");
    }
    str++;
  }
}

validation();
```

Comment: Call `str = prompt("Please Enter your email");` inside of your `else` statement. And what does `str++` do?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the while loop? What is `str++` ?

Comment: put the prompt inside while use an infinite loop like while(1) and break when the email matches

Comment: @Niladri Just check if it matches inside the condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `str` is not being updated in your loop. Your also using a `return` statement that will stop the loop after its first iteration.

You need to use `prompt("")` inside your loop and the condition to continue this loop is `str !== email`

If the message from the prompt is the same as the email, the loop will stop and code after the `while` will execute

```js
var str = prompt("Please enter your email");
var email = "test";

while (str !== email) {
  str = prompt("Please enter a valid email");
}

alert("Yeah ! Hello !");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you intended to achieve

```js
function validation() {
  var str = prompt("Please Enter your email");
  var email = "plapla@gmail.com";
  do {
    if (str === email) {
      alert("Welcome back, Logged Successfully!" + " your email is " + str);
    } else {
      str = prompt("Your Email is incorrect, Please Try again");
    }
  } while (str !== email)
}

validation();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to get the value each time you iterate, otherwise `str` isn't updated. To do so I used a [`do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop to execute it at least once, and loop while the user hasn't entered a correct value.
2. I removed `str++` from your code since it doesn't mean anything to increment ([`++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())) a string value.
3. I changed a bit your concatenation inside the `alert` to something more concise.
4. I also removed the [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statements because they would stop the execution of the function and it's not what you want.

```js
function validation() {
  do {
    var str = prompt("Please enter your email");
    var email = "plapla@gmail.com";
    
    if (str === email) {
      alert("Welcome back, Logged Successfully ! Your email is " + str);
    } else {
      alert("Your email is incorrect, please try again");
    }
  } while (str !== email) 
}

validation();
```